# setting up an ssh tunnel between client and server

Tags: ssh

I have a client and a server.  there is a firewall between them such that the client can ssh to the server, but the server can not ssh to the client.

i'd like to set up an ssh tunnel from the client to the server that would allow the server to make ssh connections back to the client.

I know there are several posts on ssh tunneling, but have not found anything that talks about this. I know its possible I just can't find it.

thanks for your time.

Comment: not sure why this was down voted. I welcome constructive criticism but just saying "your question is not any good " is hard to see as constructive.

Answer (score 1):

Try on the client
`ssh -R 45849:127.0.0.1:22 <server_user@server>`
Then on the server you should be able to do
`ssh -p 45849 <client_user@127.0.0.1>`
<del>That's if I got everything right, otherwise try switching the 45849 and the 22 on the '-R'.</del>
*Later edit:*
I've just tested it, it's all good (I was on the phone first). For something to go wrong you will have to have at least one of the following problems:

- **port forwarding disable** on either of the servers. Check with `sudo grep AllowTcpForwarding /etc/ssh/sshd_config`, make sure it says `yes`
- **sshd server binding/listening interface** on the client. Check with `sudo netstat -lntp | grep ssh`, you should see "0.0.0.0:22" listed (not sure if ":::22" helps), if you find another IP address use it instead of the "127.0.0.1" in the "-R" argument.

Comment: this is not working for me. I'm 100% sure its because i am doing something wrong.  let me see if i understand how this works..

the ssh -R 45849:127.0.0.1:22   creates a tunnel between port 45849 on the server and port 22 client   while 
<server_user@server>  is simply connecting from the client to the server. 

to get from client to server i use  ssh -l myserverid -C -p443 -C myserverip 

putting this together :
ssh -R 45849:127.0.0.1:22 serverid@serverip -p443 -C 
but this just makes a connection to my server... ssh from server to port 45849 clientid@127.0.0.1  fails

Comment: It should work . Have you done the checks I've mentioned? Running `ssh -R 45849:127.0.0.1:22 serverid@serverip -p443 -C`, should get you from the client to the server, once inside try runnig `sudo netstat -lntp | grep 45849` to check if you have the port on listening. Using the `-l user` or `user@` it's a matter of choice, they both have the same effect.

Comment: hey thanks for the response. this appears to be a problem with sshd on my client  as just ssh -l me 127.0.0.1 gives 
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Software caused connection abort

i'm asking google about that right now.